# Mapinfo wor file not working when file paths are updated using python

Tags: python, mapinfo

We did a data move and so I scripted the updating of the wor, so the old file path is changed to the new file path. It looks like it works perfectly but when I open the wor file it doesn't. When I manually go through and re-assign the file paths and then look at the wor, it is exactly the same as the auto-updated one.

Why is this?

See the wor files in https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1XGDTNNfbMJSjRkcTBrVzdkbEE&usp=sharing

- _original : before the script below was run
- _script_updated : updated by the script
- _fixed : updated manually by assigning the new file name when you open the wor in mapinfo

Script follows

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

import glob, os, csv

def inplace_change(filename, old_string, new_string):
        s=open(filename).read()
        if old_string in s:
                print 'Changing "{old_string}" to "{new_string}"'.format(**locals())
                s=s.replace(old_string, new_string)
                f=open(filename, 'w')
                f.write(s)
                f.flush()
                f.close()
                text_file = open("Process_worked.txt", "a")
                text_file.write("%s;%s;%s\n" %(worfile,old_string,new_string))
                text_file.close()
        else:
            print 'No occurances of "{old_string}" found.'.format(**locals())
            text_file = open("Process_notfound.txt", "a")
            text_file.write("%s;%s;%s\n" %(worfile,old_string,new_string))
            text_file.close()

#worfile='Bruce Workspace_13-06-2008.wor'
csvfile='File_Locations.csv'
special='Open Table \"'
wor_list=glob.glob('*.wor')

for worfile in wor_list:
    print worfile
    r = csv.DictReader(open(csvfile, "rt"), dialect="excel")
    for row in r:
        old_string=row['Existing File Path']+row['File Name']
        new_string=row['New File Path']+'\\'+row['New Name']
        print old_string, new_string
        inplace_change(worfile,old_string,new_string)
        inplace_change(worfile,row['File Name'],row['New Name'])
```

Comment: I checked and your _fixed is completely missing first layer RATES compared to _original and _updated. Why is that?

Comment: @Miro yes that's no longer required so the script took it out.

Comment: Went through it today again and as far as your paths are correct to existing files I do not see reason why it shouldn't work. Also be aware your file have labels specifications and if the new files do not have specific columns in these layers, it will cause troubles.

Comment: @Miro thanks - actually I just deleted the Rates line as it was no longer required and forgot to take it out of the original file before I uploaded it -sorry for the confusion... This would not have had an impact on whatever issue caused the script updated version not to work. I wonder if it has anything to do with the type of txt file? I just can't figure it out as text editing the wor to have the new path using notepad or notepad++ works fine as well.

Comment: Both original and updated are in UTF-8 without BOM. How did you get to line 28 label changed from With Road_name to Road_Reserves_name? Is Mapinfo gibing you some error warning when loading the workspace?

Comment: @Miro The names/paths change as they are coming from a csv that has old file name/path and new file name/path. The idea was it to cycle through the hunders of changed datasets and change these in the dozens of relevant wor's. The updated wor's just don't open, no data is shown and no errors....which is what's confusing me.

Comment: What I try to point out is that it is not only file names/paths what you need to care for. Every layer in your workspace has by default set label to some column. And you need to make sure new layers have these columns, otherwise the workspace won't load properly. Also on line 28 in your _script_updated example the label name was changed and I wonder how when your script is only about updating file paths.

Comment: Actually now I see why that label name on line 28 was changed. You change key word from Road to Road_Reserves. That is ok for you file name. But it also changed column name on that line 28. So unless in your new file Road_Reserves_Reserves which you  load as Road_Reserves you have column Road_Reserves_name, your workspace won't load.